# No features returned when using HTSeq to count transcriptome reads mapped to reference genome CDS

Tags: bioinformatics

I have a transcriptome sample that I want to map to a bacterial genome cds reference. After this, I want to then count the number of hits to each gene in the cds reference. I mapped the sample to the reference with BWA v0.7.3a with no issues but I am having a lot of issues using HTSeq v2.0.2 to count the number of hits to each gene in the cds reference.

Below is an example of my HTSeq command:

```
htseq-count -a 0 -t CDS -i product -m intersection-strict -s no Test.sam Tricho.gff
```

Below is the first 10 lines of my gff to give an indication of its format:

```
##gff-version 3
#Genome: 203124.6|Trichodesmium erythraeum IMS101
#Date:06/18/2017

##sequence-region       accn|NC_008312  1       7750108
accn|NC_008312  PATRIC  CDS     531     1397    .       +       0       ID=fig|203124.6.peg.1;locus_tag=Tery_0001;product=Chromosomal replication initiator protein DnaA;gene=dnaA
accn|NC_008312  PATRIC  CDS     1489    1689    .       -       0       ID=fig|203124.6.peg.2;locus_tag=Tery_0002;product=Mobile element protein
accn|NC_008312  PATRIC  CDS     9168    9395    .       +       0       ID=fig|203124.6.peg.7;product=DNA polymerase III beta subunit (EC 2.7.7.7);Ontology_term=GO:0003887;ec_number=2.7.7.7
accn|NC_008312  PATRIC  CDS     10371   10973   .       +       0       ID=fig|203124.6.peg.8;locus_tag=Tery_0008;product=DNA polymerase III beta subunit (EC 2.7.7.7);Ontology_term=GO:0003887;ec_number=2.7.7.7
accn|NC_008312  PATRIC  CDS     11838   12341   .       -       0       ID=fig|203124.6.peg.9;locus_tag=Tery_0010;product=Mobile element protein
```

The command I used above produces the following result:

```
3419 GFF lines processed.
33731 alignment record pairs processed.
(2E%2C6E)-farnesyl diphosphate synthase (EC 2.5.1.10)   0
(R)-citramalate synthase (EC 2.3.1.182) 0
etc. . . . through all the features in alphabetical order . . . 
__no_feature    26670
__ambiguous     0
__too_low_aQual 0
__not_aligned   7061
__alignment_not_unique  0
```

Other help forums online seem to solve this issue by using GTF files instead of a GFF but I don't have a GTF easily available.

Any explanation and help solving this issue would be very appreciated!

Comment: I wonder if using the `product` is causing some problems. What output do you get when you use `-i gene`? What process created the GFF, or where did it come from?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use -i gene because not all lines in my gff have a gene = xxxxx field. This gff came from a collaborator who I think (but am not 100% sure) got it from the PATRIC database.

Comment: I did also try -i ID and received a similar error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my question using a python script from a collaborator. The script makes a GTF2 file from the reference fasta file used for my BWA run.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#Converts FastaFile to a faux GTF file
import sys
from Bio import SeqIO
import numpy
import re

#CHANGE ME!
handle = open("Merged_reference2.fna", "r", newline=None) 
gtf2Out = "Merged_ref2.gtf2"

# Merged_reference2.fna is the fasta file I used to make an index for BWA. 

#DON'T CHANGE ME!

file2 = open(gtf2Out,'w+')
file2.write("##gtf-version 2")
file2.write("\n")
#gff Fields are: <seqname> <source> <feature> <start> <end> <score> <strand> <frame> [attributes] [comments]


#Getting error message from HTSeq-count so trying to convert to gtf 2 instead of gff3
#Main problem appears to be an issue with the attribute section of the file (last column).

#so, broke apart the whole title of the fasta and converted it to the format: attribute "description";

for record in SeqIO.parse(handle, "fasta"):
        seqLen=len(record.seq)
        seqID=record.id
        attributeStr="gene_id " + '"'+ seqID + '"; ' + "transcript_id " + '"'+ seqID + '.01";'

#       lister=[seqID, ".", "exon", 1, seqLen, ".", "+", "0", "."]
#       for item in lister:
#               file.write("%s\t" % item)
#       file.write("\n")

        lister2=[seqID, ".", "exon", 1, seqLen, ".", "+", "0", attributeStr]
        for item in lister2:
                file2.write("%s\t" % item)
        file2.write("\n")


handle.close()
file2.close()
```